# Trying to understand this line of Tcl code

Tags: tcl

I want to know ICCII command for this particular line

```
set layer_name [get_object_name [lsort -unique [get_attribute [get_drc_error -error_id [get_object_name $eid]] layers]]]
```

and what exactly this command is doing...I'm getting error nothing implicitly matched

Tell me how to correct his command

Answer (score 0):

I think that's excessively much in one line; it obscures problems and confuses when you put too much together. Let's split it up with the help of some temporary variables:

```
set obj_name [get_object_name $eid]
set layers [get_attribute [get_drc_error -error_id $obj_name] layers]
set unique_layers [lsort -unique $layers]
set layer_name [get_object_name $unique_layers]
```

The most likely problem here is that `lsort -unique` might still be producing multiple layer IDs, whereas `get_object_name` can only handle one thing. Assuming you're using Tcl 8.6, that last line would become:

```
set layer_names [lmap layer $unique_layers {get_object_name $layer}]
```

Or perhaps:

```
set layer_name [get_object_name [lindex $unique_layers 0]]
```

In 8.5 and before, you don't have `lmap` and have to use `foreach` instead:

```
set layer_names {}
foreach layer $unique_layers {
    lappend layer_names [get_object_name $layer]
}
```

The extra code is pretty much exactly what `lmap` does for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot .  set net_name [get_object_name [get_attribute [get_drc_error -error_id  [get_object_name $eid]] nets]]

Comment: what exactly this command is doing and how to correct this command,It's in ICC and I want to change it into ICCII

Comment: when I'm trying to execute this command it's giving error for get_drc_error command